# How to set number of relations between nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created a transport route of station nodes connected by a :CONNECTION type session, if it is a transfer, I have a :EXCHANGE session type.
I'm looking for a route using a query

```sql
MATCH path = (from:Station {id: 61})-[:IN]->(sec_from:Section),
              (to:Station {id: 131})<-[:OUT]-(sec_to:Section),
              route=(sec_from)-[:CONNECTION|EXCHANGE*]->(sec_to)
RETURN route;
```

If I want to search for direct connections only, I use:
`route=(sec_from)-[:CONNECTION*]->(sec_to)` , it works. If I want to limit the number of connections to 5-10, I use: `route=(sec_from)-[:CONNECTION*5..10]->(sec_to)` also works. But if I want to have a connection of type :CONNECTION 1-100 and at the same time type :EXCHANGE 0-3, the query doesn't work:

```sql
MATCH path = (from:Station {id: 61})-[:IN]->(sec_from:Section),
              (to:Station {id: 131})<-[:OUT]-(sec_to:Section),
              route=(sec_from)-[:CONNECTION*1..100|EXCHANGE*0..3]->(sec_to)
RETURN route;
```

What is the correct syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've written in the question, the straightforward way would be to add constraints on the number of each relationship type in a `WHERE` clause:

```sql
MATCH path = (from:Station {id: 61})-[:IN]->(sec_from:Section), 
      (to:Station {id: 131})<-[:OUT]-(sec_to:Section), 
      route = (sec_from)-[r:CONNECTION|EXCHANGE*1..103]->(sec_to) 
WHERE 1 <= size([rel IN r WHERE rel:CONNECTION]) <= 100 
      AND size([rel IN r WHERE rel:EXCHANGE]) <= 3
RETURN route;
```

Depending on your data, a post-filter like this could be inefficient, as it might fetch many paths with > 3 relationships of type `EXCHANGE` before discarding them at the `WHERE` clause stage.

Comment: thanks, this is where the problem is, the data is filtered only after the result is received. is there no other way to discard the selection if I reach the n-number of EXCHANGE?

Comment: I am not aware of one. This does give the correct results, though.